# How to replace content of <li> tag

Tags: jquery, html

I'm quite new here, and just recently discovered jQuery.
I have a list:

```
<ul id="tagcloud">
    <li>Strategic Planning Process,Preparing for Changes,</li>
    <li>Effective,Enrollment Managers,Effective Enrollment Managers,</li>
    <li>Enrollment Program,</li>
    <li>Next Generation,Diversity,Future enrollment,</li>
    <li>Annual Admissions Plan,</li>
</ul>
```

Now, what i want to do, is basicly replace all the "," with `</li><li>` and, of course, get rid of the last "," not to have empty `<li>`
I think its gonna be something like:

```
$('pre').html(function() {
   return this.innerHTML.replace(",", "</li><li>");
});
```

But it doesnt work. I'm probably thinking wrong...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$('pre')` selects `pre` elements. In addition, [`replace` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) only replaces the first occurence of a string unless provided a regular expression with global flag.

I guess you want

```
$('#tagcloud').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/,/g, "</li><li>");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ggXtF/)

Alternatively, to not create empty `li` elements (which happens if the comma is at the end), you can take the text only:

```
$('#tagcloud').html(function(i, html) {
    return '<li>' + $(this).text().replace(/,/g, '</li><li>') + '</li>';
    // or
    // return '<li>' + $(this).text().split(',').join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ggXtF/2/)

---

Further reading:

- [Regular expressions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: I don't know if this is the place, but can you briefly tell me what `/,/g` is doing? is it in the jQuery replace docs?

Comment: @Phil: `replace` is a JavaScript function. `/,/g` is a regex literal. The `/` mark the beginning and the end of the literal and `g` is a modifier. I added a link.

Comment: It works great, but I'm wondering why there is a whitespace in li content (<li> something</li>)
I tried to use .trim() but can't really find the way...

Comment: @Mateusz: You mean when using `text()`? This is because the HTML code contains line breaks too and `text()` gets all the text, not only the one that is inside the `li` elements. You could do something like `$.map($(this).text().split(','), $trim).join(...)` but you actually don't have to worry about that. White spaces directly after an opening tag are usually ignored (not rendered).

Answer (score 0):

Felix Kling's answer works to replace the commas with list items but does avoid creating empty elements from the extraneous ending comma on the last item.  Also, directly editing HTML (using the DOM element's innerHTML property) can be faster than using DOM manipulation functions, but AFAIK is not always reliable/compatible (brief example mentioned here http://api.jquery.com/html/), and I recommend working with elements instead.

Try something like:

```
$('#tagcloud').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();         
    if(text.substr(text.length - 1) == ',') {
       $(this).text(text.substr(0, text.length - 2));
    }

    var items = text.split(',');
    if(items.length > 1) {
        $(this).text(text.substr(0, text.indexOf(',') - 1);
        var newItems = [];

        for(i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
            var newItem = document.createElement("li");
            $(newItem).text(items[i]);
            newItems.push(newItem);
        }
        $(this).after($(newItems));
    }
 }
```

Just writing this off the top of my head, but what this does is check if the last character of the list item's text is a comma, in which case it is removed.  Then make an array of the text delimited by the comma, and if there are any extra list items to be created, it cuts the item's text down to the first item.  Then it builds an array of DOM elements from the rest of the text items to be created, and inserts them following the first list item.

Comment: I started this answer before he edited his post to include accommodation for the extraneous element.  I believe his update would work fine for editing the HTML directly.